# Problems with implementing a realtime update with Rails5 and Actioncable

Tags: ruby, websocket, real-time, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to implement a simple rails fullstack todo app with action cable.
Unfortunately the docs on action cable is still confusing to me.
I tried to refer to DHH's example and https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable and adjusting to my app https://github.com/tenzan/rails-fullstack-todo

It's not showing realtime updates at http://localhost:3000/tasks when I used one browser for task creation and another one to see if it changes automatically.

My environment:

1. Mac OS X Sierra
2. Rails 5.0.0.1
3. Ruby 2.4.0
4. Redis enabled in Gemfile and running at port `6379`
5. RethinkDB

I implemented:

**app/assets/javascripts/channels/index.coffee**

```
//= require cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree .

this.App = {};

App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
```

**app/assets/javascripts/channels/tasks.js**

```
App.tasks = App.cable.subscriptions.create('TasksChannel', {
  received: function(data) {
    $("#tasks").removeClass('hidden')
    return $('#tasks').append(this.renderTask(data));
  }
});
```

**app/channels/tasks_channel.rb**

```
class TasksChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "tasks"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
```

**app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'tasks', task: @task.title
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**: Added `<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>`

**config/cable.yml**

```
local: &local
  url: redis://localhost:6379

development: *local
test: *local
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**app/views/tasks/index.html.erb**

I suspect something wrong with

1. `app/assets/javascripts/channels/tasks.coffee`
2. `app/views/tasks/index.html.erb`

But I really don't have an idea how to fix/adjust them.